# javascript prototype not working

Tags: prototype, javascript, function-prototypes

Am I mistaking what `.prototype` is supposed to do, or is this just not working??

```
window.dump = function () {
    for (var i = 0, x = dump.list.length; i < x; ++i) console.log.apply(this, dump.list[i]);
    if (arguments.length && typeof arguments[0] === 'boolean' && arguments[0]) dump.purge();
}
dump.prototype = {
    list : [],
    log : function () {
        dump.list.push(arguments);
    },
    purge : function () {
        dump.list = [];
    }
}
dump.log('test1');
dump.log('test2');
dump();
```

I expect "test1" and "test2" to be passed through `console.log`, instead `dump.log` is not defined. However `dump.prototype.log` is.

edit: I've tried the following, and I just can't seem to get this prototype thing right.

```
window.dump = new function () {
    this.list = [];
    this.log = function () {
        this.list.push(arguments);
    }
    this.purge = function () {
        return this.list = [];
    }
    return function () {
        for (var i = 0, x = this.list.length; i < x; ++i) console.log.apply(this, this.list[i]);
        if (arguments.length && typeof arguments[0] === 'boolean' && arguments[0]) this.purge();
    }
}
```

I guess what I'm asking is, what is the correct way to be able to use my code as follows?

```
dump.log('test1');
dump.log('test2');
dump();
```

edit: Here's a final result thanks to Matthew Flaschen, for anyone who's interested in building from it.

```
(function () {
    var console_log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
    window.dump = function () {
        for (var i = 0, x = dump.list.length; i < x; ++i) console_log.apply(this, dump.list[i]);
        if (arguments.length && typeof arguments[0] === 'boolean' && arguments[0]) dump.purge();
    };
    dump.list = [];
    dump.log = function () {
        dump.list.push(arguments);
    }
    dump.purge = function () {
        dump.list = [];
    }
})();
```

I've had to assign `console_log` to wrap `console.log`, because apparently `console` is not a standard object. Therefore it is not a standard `Function` object with the `apply` method. Proof that I do actually use Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a correct version would be the below.  `dumper` is a constructor function.  Thus, it initializes the `list` member.

Below, we set the `dumper` prototype with the desired methods.  These can also use `this`.  Any instance of `dumper` (such as `d`) will have these methods.

```
window.dumper = function () {
    this.list = [];
};

dumper.prototype = {

    log : function () {
        this.list.push(arguments);
    },
    purge : function () {
        this.list = [];
    },
    dump : function () {
        for (var i = 0, x = this.list.length; i < x; ++i) console.log.apply(this, this.list[i]);
        if (arguments.length && typeof arguments[0] === 'boolean' && arguments[0]) this.purge();
    }
}


var d = new dumper();        

d.log('test1');
d.log('test2');
d.dump();
```

Comment: there is no way to actually use "d" as the dump function?

Comment: @andrewjackson, probably if you make `dump` a singleton.  But that defeats the whole point of using `prototype`.  Don't try to fight the JavaScript object model unless you have to.

Comment: I don't want to be a pain, but do you have an example of what a singleton would look like, that would make this possible? just for informational purposes...